Define $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}^n)$ by $T(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1,2x_2,3x_2,\ldots, nx_n)$. Find the minimal polynomial of $T$.
The following is an exercise in "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler, 4th edition.

Define $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F}^n)$ by $T(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_n) = (x_1,2x_2,3x_2,\ldots, nx_n)$. Find the minimal polynomial of $T$.

This is how I approached the problem:
Choosing the standard basis of $\mathbb{F}^n$, the matrix of $T$ is
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n \end{pmatrix}
$$
To find the minimal polynomial of $T$, we need to find the smallest positive integer $m$ such that
$$
c_0I + c_1A + c_2A^2 + \cdots + c_{m-1}A^{m-1} = - A^m \tag{1}
$$
has a solution $c_0, c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_{m-1} \in \mathbb{F}$. It's easy to show that
$$
A^k = \tag{2}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 2^k & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3^k & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n^k \end{pmatrix}
$$
for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Using $(2)$ and $(1)$, we get the following system of $n$ linear equations:
\begin{cases}
c_0 + c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + \cdots + c_{m-1} = -1 \\
c_0 + 2c_1 + 2^2c_2 + 2^3c_3 + \cdots + 2^{m-1}c_{m-1} = -2^m \\
c_0 + 3c_1 + 3^2c_2 + 3^3c_3 + \cdots + 3^{m-1}c_{m-1} = -3^m \\
\cdots \\
c_0 + nc_1 + n^2c_2 + n^3c_3 + \cdots + n^{m-1}c_{m-1} = -n^m 
\end{cases}

This is where I got stuck. Without an actual value for $n$, how am I supposed to solve this system? Even for an $n$ large, this system would be torture to solve. I decided to use a minimal polynomial calculator online on various choices for $n$ - upon observation, I extrapolated that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is
$$
p(z) = (z-n)(z-(n-1))\cdots (z-3)(z-2)(z-1)
$$
But how can I get to this without such a tool? Am I supposed to use a different strategy as opposed to the above work?

There is no need to use the characteristic polynomial for this exercise. Just use the result that the zeros of the minimal polynomial are the eigenvalues (Theorem 5.27 of Linear Algebra Done Right, fourth edition) and the result that the minimal polynomial has degree at most $n$ (Theorem 5.22 of Linear Algebra Done Right, fourth edition).
The electronic version of Linear Algebra Done Right, fourth edition, is freely (and legally) available at https://linear.axler.net/.

Ah, of course! Thank you, Mr. Axler, for your time.

And just so I'm clear, I cannot simply use result 5.27(b) because that only applies if the space is complex, right?

Yes, you are correct that 5.27(b) applies only to complex vector spaces. However, when I wrote to use 5.27, I meant 5.27(a), which applies to both real and complex vector spaces.

A property of the minimal polynomial $M_A \in \newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}} \F[x]$ (for $A$) is that, if $p \in \F[x]$ has the property $p(A) = 0$, then $M_A \mid p$. This is the minimality of that polynomial, where the name comes from.
A particular case of note is the characteristic polynomial, $C_A(\lambda) := \det(A - \lambda I)$ (or equivalently, $\det(\lambda I - A)$). The Cayley-Hamilton theorem tells us that $C_A(A)=0$; hence $M_A \mid C_A$.
Now, clearly, for your matrix,
$$
C_A(\lambda) = \prod_{k=1}^n (k-\lambda) \text{ or equivalently } \prod_{k=1}^n (\lambda-k)
$$
and this is a product of linear factors, so $M_A$ must be a product of some subset thereof. Question is: which ones?
Another result tells us that these statements are equivalent:

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$
$\lambda$ is a root of $C_A$
$\lambda$ is a  root of $M_A$

Consequently, if a characteristic polynomial may be factored in the form
$$
C_A(\lambda) = \prod_i (\lambda - \lambda_i)^{m_i}
$$
then we have that
$$
M_A(\lambda) = \prod_i (\lambda - \lambda_i)^{e_i} \text{ where } e_i \in \{1,2,\cdots,m_i\}
$$
In particular, this means that if a linear nonrepeated factor appears in the characteristic polynomial, it must appear in the minimal polynomial.
Hence, for your matrix, $C_A = M_A$.

Hello! Thank you for your answer and your time. I think I understand your solution, but is there a method without using the characteristic polynomial?

I mean, maybe, but why would you want one without it, especially if it has such a nice form and is trivial to find?

It's a silly ask, I know. Reason being is that the text introduces determinants (and hence, characteristic polynomials) dead last. I think the author intended some other method to find the minimal polynomial in this exercise. One of those methods is what I attempted above.
